# How to make middle TD higher than side ones?

Tags: html, css

I have table with 3 cells, and I want to make middle one higher than side ones, so for example middle one's height is 300px and side one's is 200px. I gave middle one seperate class than side ones and I set middle one to 300px and side ones to 200px. But they are still the same height, why?

```css
#mid {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.side {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="side"></td>
    <td id="mid"></td>
    <td class="side"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: All cells within a single table row will always have the same height. This is how HTML tables work. If you want to create something that doesn't look or behave like a table, it may be better to choose different HTML elements.

Comment: HTML tables are for tabular data, it is discouraged to use them to organize a visual layout that don't directly correspond to tabular layout (where a row has a constant height). Use `div` or something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only use tables for tabular data and not for layout.  What you are trying to do is not achievable with a table as all table cells in a row will be the same height as the tallest cell of that row.

Instead you should use divs, in the following example I have used flexbox to align the divs in a row:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.mid {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.side {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="side"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did that and I tried to inline it but it just doens't work

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  If you can show me your attempt, I can tell you what is wrong

Comment: I can't get DIV elements in one line that's all

Comment: that's what the display flex on the container is for - it lines up the child divs in a row

Answer (score 1):

LIke others have mentioned in comments you are better off using a div or some other tags
but if you still want to use table you can do something like this

```
<table>

          <tr>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td id = "mid" rowspan="2"></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
          <tr>
               <td class = "side"></td>
               <td></td>
               <td class ="side"></td>
           </tr>
  </table>
```

here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vdadekvL/28/